# Continue reading wordpress inside post

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How do I insert a button like "continue reading" inside the post, [with this style in wordpress?](https://catracalivre.com.br/geral/mundo-animal/indicacao/professora-ja-encontrou-mais-de-70-lares-pra-animais-perdidos/) [or this](http://climatologiageografica.com.br/10-fatos-estranhos-e-curiosos-sobre-maconha/)
Without using bb code, and before second paragraph.

Comment: You maybe looking for this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Comment: I need a "Continue reading" button, the infinite scroll the template already has. Thank you @FarizLuqman

Comment: if you want the continue reading button to be on the current post, you can just use the "more" tag: https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/

Answer (score 0):

**Step -1 :** Go to Setting->reading and select Summary and save changes.

**Step -2 :** We need to add the link text at the end of each excerpt. To do this we need to work inside a different file called functions.php.

Find it and open it inside your code editor.

Scroll to the very bottom and add this block of PHP code:

```
/* Modify the read more link on the_excerpt() */

function et_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 220;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'et_excerpt_length');

/* Add a link  to the end of our excerpt contained in a div for styling purposes and to break to a new line on the page.*/

function et_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '<div class="view-full-post"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="view-full-post-btn">View Full Post</a></div>;';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'et_excerpt_more');
```

For more reference find this:
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-customize-the-wordpress-read-more-link-text